# What property of Riemann integrals in general that makes it not complete?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, complete-spaces

I know that I can find a sequence of functions that are Riemann integrable but converges to a function f that is not Riemann integrable and this would show that the space of all Riemann integrable functions is not complete. but what property of the space that makes it true abstractly. Is it because $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} f_{n}  dx =\int_{a}^{b} f dx $$  iff $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly not point-wise . while the above property in Lebesgue integrals could be true with point-wise convergence only? I mean, In general why Lebesgue integrable functions form a complete space but not all the Riemann integrable functions can?

Comment: Lebesgue integrabilty does nor require any continuity property whereas Riemann integrability require  almost everywhere continuity.

Comment: Ok thanks!! .. but how is continuing is related to convergence of Cauchy sequences?

Comment: I think that a Riemann integrable being necessarily bounded and also the fact that individual values of the function on an infinite set, however small in other ways (eg countable) being crucial to Riemann integration are also a problem - think of a sequence that is $\log x, \frac{1}{n} \le x \le 1$, $-\log n$ in the rest of $[0,1]$ or a sequence that is $0$ except on the first $n$ rationals in $[0,1]$ in some numbering and $1$ there...